# How do I place everything in correct places?

Tags: html, css, header, nav

I'm beginner in html/css and I have a problem. The problem is that I try to place navigation items on its background image. I have two monitors, laptop and a desktop monitor, if I code on laptop, everything seems fine till I drag the browser tab to my desktop monitor. Everything is out of position again and I do not know how to fix it myself, I've tried everything I know already.

The code:

```css
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 11%;
    margin-top: -500px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 41px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-style: italic;
    /* font-family: "Lucida Sans"; */
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.nav-background {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -470px;
    left: 58%;
}

.nav-item-a {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 890px;
    margin-top: -450px;
}

.nav-item-b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    margin-top: -450px;
}

.nav-item-c {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%;
    margin-top: -450px;
}

.nav-item-a, .nav-item-b, .nav-item-c {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9B7D08;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header class="block">    
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="..." class="logo-img">
            <h1>Theyalow</h1>
        </div> 
        <nav class="nav">
            <img src="assets/images/nav-back.png" alt="..." class="nav-background">
            <a class="nav-item-a" href="">about-us</a>
            <a class="nav-item-b" href="">services</a>
            <a class="nav-item-c" href="">contact</a>
        </nav>
</header>
```

The screenshots of the problem:
Laptop screen: https://prnt.sc/XykzCALDd4Zk
Desktop screen: https://prnt.sc/p390j4jITVg2

Comment: Don't mix `%` and `px`. Don't use absolute positioning for large scale layout. Learn flexbox and grid.

Answer (score -1):

Using specific measurements like `px` will cause this as your laptop screen and desktop screen have different height and width to each other.

Here are some solutions

1. Media queries. You can manually alter the sizing and positioning based on the size of the screen its being displayed on. Although this is quite tedious and not best practice.
   Here's a link - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
2. Flexbox. Flexbox is very powerful in this department. Specifically `flex-basis` `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow`. Here's a link - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
3. Combining the two together. Set up your base code with flexbox and set up media queries for the font and anything that still isn't quite right.

This sort of thing used to drive me crazy until I got the hang of flexbox